# reverse_iterator behaviour with const char[]

Tags: c++, iterator

Having the objects below:

```
const char      a[]{"abcdefghij"}; // Array of characters (length 11)
const std::string s{"abcdefghij"}; // Standard basic_string<char>
```

I expect the following loops to behave equally:

```
// #1 Outputs NOTHING, expected "jihgfedcba"
for (auto begin = std::rbegin(a), end = std::rend(a); begin != end; ++begin)
    std::cout << *begin;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

```
// #2 Outputs "jihgfedcba", as expected
for (auto begin = std::rbegin(s), end = std::rend(s); begin != end; ++begin)
    std::cout << *begin;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

But printing the array of characters outputs nothing while printing the string shows the expected output.

Printing the array of characters also affects the printing the string: if the #1 loop is written before the #2 the program outputs nothing but reversing the order a single `jihgfedcba` is shown.

---

I noticed that tweaking the return value of `std::rbegin(a)` fixes the problem:

```
// Outputs "jihgfedcba", as expected
// notice the ++!!
for (auto begin = ++std::rbegin(a), end = std::rend(a); begin != end; ++begin)
    std::cout << *begin;
std::cout << std::endl;

// Outputs "jihgfedcba", as expected
for (auto begin = std::rbegin(s), end = std::rend(s); begin != end; ++begin)
    std::cout << *begin;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

---

Why is this happening?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Both loops produce the same result for me. Except that for the const char[] there is an extra empty space printed in front ('\0' most likely).

Comment: @DeiDei let me provide you a [code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/k1RqUEKvVRxedJVf) which shows the described behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array of `char` contain:

```
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', '\0'} // 11 characters
```

While the `std::string` contain:

```
"abcdefghij" // 10 characters
```

In the first case, the last character (first in the loop) is '\0'. When you "tweak" the loop, you skip this character.

Even if I am unable to reproduce your behaviour, I expect this to be the source of the issue.

Comment: This explains part of the *issue*. But it doesn't explain why printing (without tweaking) the array of `char` prevents any following output in the console.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce that. In my case it print both correctly even without tweaking. Which console do you use?

Comment: I observed this behaviour in the [Wandbox console](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/k1RqUEKvVRxedJVf) with the last gcc and clang compilers.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: Looking the code of your comment, it works with both for me. (I just Run them again and it show correct output)